# Summation of columns in matrix into an array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need a formula that takes the values from a matrix, sums the columns and returns an array (the rows).

`SUM()` only seems to return a single value when summing both matrices and arrays, and my formula needs to return an array. It also needs to fit inside a single cell. For you to get an idea of what I'm looking for, if I were only using two arrays, my code would look like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A10+B1:B10)
```

However, I need to sum an undefined amount of arrays element-wise, and not end up with a single value.

Comment: by "undefined amount of arrays" you mean "a lots of columns" ? or you mean you have no idea what is the last column?

Comment: I basically cannot use '+' for every column individually, because I don't know how many columns the matrix will contain. @player0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

formulas for the multi-column sum are:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(A1:Z1), ROW(A1:A1000)), ROW(A1:A1000), A1:Z1000))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IFERROR(VALUE(A1:Z1000), 0), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:Z1000)^0)))
```

if the last column is dynamic you will need to do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IFERROR(VALUE(INDIRECT("A1:"&ADDRESS(1000, COLUMNS(A:AAA), 4))), 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(INDIRECT("A1:"&ADDRESS(1000, COLUMNS(A:AAA), 4)))^0)))
```

### _______________________________________________________________

[image: 0]

cell **D2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1)); 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F2:I16&":");;999^99)); " "; ""); ))
```

cell **E19**:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FILTER(INDIRECT("D2:D"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1); 
 COUNTIF(B19:B; INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1))); ":"; 1; 0)*C19:C); 
 COUNTA(B19:B); COUNTA(E18:18))
```

cell **J20**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(":"; MMULT(
 TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("E19:"&ADDRESS(21; COLUMN()-2; 4))); 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(10; COUNTA(E19:E)); 1))^0)))&":"
```

**note:** **`COLUMN()-2`** means that the sum is located two columns from end of the table

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a matrix that is not tied to specific cells? For example with multiple arrays from the split()-function formed as a matrix. (Example matrix: split(filter(C:C;B:B=A1);":";1;0), where the cells in B:B all are numbers separated by ':', like 1:2:3:4:5)

Comment: My main sheet is a mess, but I set up another sheet that is pretty much what I am after: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F6dEKPV5yqf8UqWCu9Dv4VrfBCo8bS0mkYy8WEv8OKA/edit?usp=sharing